# Problema con VsCode no me funcionan caracteres

Tags: vscode

Tengo el siguiente problema que no puedo solucionar. Estuve utilizando una extension en vsCode similar a github Copilot que me pedía que configure los atajos de teclado. Luego de desinstalarla me quedaron desconfigurados los atajos y no me toma los caracteres especiales como por ejemplo: el signo de exclamacion, signo dolar etc.

El mensaje que me aparece es este:   command 'easycode-canary.ask' not found

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? ¿Como volver a la configuracion anterior?

Comment: Fuera de VS Code: revisaste la configuración de tu teclado en window y que esté en español?

Comment: Si. si uso el editor de texto por defecto en el sistema operativo funciona bien, pero en el vsc no.

Comment: Se puede solucionar instalando la extensión de VS en español. Buscar este código en las extensiones para instalar : **MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-es**